# Can one Windows environment variable refer to another windows environment variable?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I want to support two versions of a Windows app easily.
It uses environment variables to configure it.

I'd like to set up a top level ENV, that can be changed to switch versions:

```
VERSION_ROOT = c:\tool_version_A
```

```
TOOL_BIN_FOLDER = $VERSION_ROOT\bin
TOOL_LIB_FOLDER = $VERSION_ROOT\lib
```

Then if I need to switch to tool version B, I just change the `VERSION_ROOT` environment variable: `VERSION_ROOT = c:\tool_version_B`
and I'm done.

Any way to make this work in Windows?

Comment: It's not really a question of whether Windows can do it, but rather whether the application supports it. `set TOOL_BIN_FOLDER=%%VERSION_ROOT%%\bin` inserts an unexpanded variable. You can then use ExpandEnvironmentStrings to re-expanded the nested variable in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Durn it! No - When I put %TOOL_BIN_FOLDER% in the Windows 10 environment variable edit box it IMMEDIATELY expands it to the folder location, replacing the variable with the hard wired path #facepalm.

This didn't work:
Trying to use the Windows batch file variable synth with the surrounding % signs:

TOOL_BIN_FOLDER = %VERSION_ROOT%\bin

More hints here: [Limits on Windows environment variable nesting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594846/limits-on-windows-environment-variable-nesting)